# How many subﬁelds does a ﬁeld with $2^{36} = 68719476736$ elements have

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, finite-fields

I encounter to this qustion. This is such a big number so I believe there must be some trick to solve it.

But I wonder what property of finite fields should I use. I know that according to Galois correspondence.  The subfields are correspond to divisor of $2^{36}$. Is that correct? So is are there exactly $37$ such subgroups?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The subfields correspond to divisors of $36$, not $2^{36}$ (the degree of the subfield over the prime field must divide the degree of $\mathbb F_{2^{36}}$ over $\mathbb F_2$).

Comment: @ErickWong So it there 9 such fields?

Comment: @PropositionX Are you looking for the total number of subfields, or the number of different isomorphism classes of subfields?  Those are two different problems.

Comment: @Aaron I see that those questions have different intents, but they have the same answer so calling them different problems seems a stretch.

Comment: @Aaron Total number of subfields. But are some of them isomorphic?

Comment: @PropositionX Suppose you're looking for the subfield of order $2^s$.  Every element must be a root of the polynomial $x^{2^s}-x$.  But that polynomial has at most $2^s$ roots in the larger field, so there can't be more than one subfield of that size.

Comment: @PropositionX For finite fields, two fields is isomorphic if and only if they have the same number of elements. Therefore, if you only cared which fields were subfields (and now how they were embedded), you could proceed more easily with a counting argument, instead of looking at the Galois group.

Comment: Got it! Many thanks to you who leave comments.

Comment: @Aaron If a finite field $F$ has two subfields $K_1$ and $K_2$, then $K_1=K_2$ if and only if $K_1=K_2$ (in particular if they are isomorphic).

Answer (score 0):

You may have established that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ (since you have a finite extension of finite fields).

By the converse of Lagrange's theorem (for cyclic groups), there exists subgroups $H$ which have order dividing the order of the group, namely, $|H| =2,3,4,9,6$. This is all of them (don't forget the trivial ones).

Using the fundamental theorem of Galois theory you should use that bijection you were talking about.

Comment: The subgroups are also unique.

Comment: Do not forget the divisors 12 and 18!

Comment: @PropositionX nice catch, its difficult to know if you've got them all sometimes!